# Cannot figure out how to combine arrays to be able to write to SQL columns in powershell

Tags: sql-server, powershell

I have been struggling with this for hours without any result :(. I have a select string command which finds various strings in the files

```
$sasnrs =  @(Select-String -Pattern "SASI.{11}" -path $Temp1 | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Matches)
$sassuppcars = @(Select-String -Pattern "TMB.............." -path $Temp1  | select-object -expandproperty Matches)
$sasprices = @(Select-String -Pattern '[1-2]?\.?\d{3},\d{2}' -path $Temp2 | select-object -expandproperty Matches)
```

This gets me output like this

```
PS D:\Temp> $sasnrs

Groups   : {0}
Success  : True
Name     : 0
Captures : {0}
Index    : 0
Length   : 15
Value    : SASIVB0XXXXX0

Groups   : {0}
Success  : True
Name     : 0
Captures : {0}
Index    : 0
Length   : 15
Value    : SASIIM0XXXX659

Groups   : {0}
Success  : True
Name     : 0
Captures : {0}
Index    : 0
Length   : 15
Value    : SASIIMXXXXXXX9

PS D:\Temp> $sassuppcars


Groups   : {0}
Success  : True
Name     : 0
Captures : {0}
Index    : 18
Length   : 17
Value    : TMBXXXXXXX90

Groups   : {0}
Success  : True
Name     : 0
Captures : {0}
Index    : 17
Length   : 17
Value    : TMBXXXXXXXXX5625

Groups   : {0}
Success  : True
Name     : 0
Captures : {0}
Index    : 17
Length   : 17
Value    : TMBXXXXXXX303

PS D:\Temp> $sasprices
Groups   : {0}
Success  : True
Name     : 0
Captures : {0}
Index    : 102
Length   : 6
Value    : 824,57

Groups   : {0}
Success  : True
Name     : 0
Captures : {0}
Index    : 102
Length   : 6
Value    : 683,97

Groups   : {0}
Success  : True
Name     : 0
Captures : {0}
Index    : 102
Length   : 6
Value    : 487,38
```

I have 4 columns created in SQL server, first one is constant, and I need to fill out rest of the three, unfortunately, when I run ForEach loop on every value of every variable, this example would create 9 rows instead of three

```
            ForEach($Sasnr in $Sasnrs){
                $SQLSuppNRQuery = "INSERT INTO dbo.Podpory (Marken, Doklad) VALUES ('$sasmark', '$sasnr');"    
                Invoke-Sqlcmd -ServerInstance $SQLSuppSERVER -Database $SQLSuppDatabase -Query 

$SQLSuppNRQuery
                                        }
                ForEach($sassuppcar in $sassuppcars) {
                    $SQLSuppVINQuery = "INSERT INTO dbo.Podpory (VIN) VALUES ('$sassuppcar');"    
                    Invoke-Sqlcmd -ServerInstance $SQLSuppSERVER -Database $SQLSuppDatabase -Query $SQLSuppVINQuery
                                        }
                ForEach($sasprice in $sasprices){
                    $SQLSuppPRQuery = "INSERT INTO dbo.Podpory (Suma) VALUES ('$sasprice');"    
                    Invoke-Sqlcmd -ServerInstance $SQLSuppSERVER -Database $SQLSuppDatabase -Query $SQLSuppPRQuery
                                        }
```

Something like this

[image]

I tried creating a hashtable, but I am having troubles understanding the concept and using it in a SQL query.

Thank you very much for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do, I'm just not sure of what the source type object types are for the variables holding the values.

```
$count = $sasnrs.count // Assuming they all have the same count here...
$i = 0
do {
                $query = "INSERT INTO dbo.Podpory (Marken,Doklad,VIN,Suma) VALUES ('$sasmark','$($sasnrs[$i].Value)','$($sassuppcars[$i].Value)','$($sasprices[$i].Value)');"    
                Invoke-Sqlcmd -ServerInstance $SQLSuppSERVER -Database $SQLSuppDatabase -Query $query
$i++
} until ($i -eq ($count - 1))
```

Comment: Was on my phone, kindly forgive indentation.

Comment: Thank you for the response, this however puts all 3 values into one column, thus creating only one line of data with 3 data in single cell :(.

Comment: Try this: `$query = "INSERT INTO dbo.Podpory (Marken,Doklad,VIN,Suma) VALUES ('$sasmark','$($sasnrs[$i].Value)','$($sassuppcars[$i].Value)','$($sasprices[$i].Value)');" `

Comment: This produces two empty lines, when I input 

PS D:\Temp>  $sasnrs[0]
SASIVB000241660

PS D:\Temp> $sasprices[0]
824,57

PS D:\Temp> $sasprices[1]
683,97

PS D:\Temp> $sasprices[2]
487,38


I get correct values, but not in a query

Comment: I think this answer looks good but has some syntax errors.  Change `VALUES ('$sasmark','$sasnrs[$i].Value','$sassuppcars[$i].Value','$sasprices[$i].Value')` to `VALUES ('$sasmark','$($sasnrs[$i].Value)','$($sassuppcars[$i].Value)','$($sasprices[$i].Value)')`.  To access object properties inside of a double-quotes you have to wrap in `$( )` https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/learn/deep-dives/everything-about-string-substitutions?view=powershell-7.1#command-substitution

Comment: @Snake, can you please share what values are being inserted?

Comment: @alexzelaya - Hi, the problem was at my end, I thought putting -split "´n" to foreach queries would put it on the new lines :D I removed those, and commented out - 1 in $count - 1 part, because only n - 1 was getting inserted (last one was not). Thank you very much for your help :)